# Enabling Submit Button after clicking checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have been struggling with getting the following code to work (example taken from jsfiddle after looking at responses in this forum.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

checkboxes.click(function() {
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
      </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Button should be enabled if at least one checkbox is checked</h1>

<form>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-1" id="option-1"> <label for="option-1">Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-2" id="option-2"> <label for="option-2">Option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-3" id="option-3"> <label for="option-3">Option 3</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-4" id="option-4"> <label for="option-4">Option 4</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-5" id="option-5"> <label for="option-5">Option 5</label>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Do thing" disabled>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It's working perfectly fine, your snippet doesn't work because you added the `<script>` tags in the javascript pane -> https://jsfiddle.net/vvoycf38/

Comment: Thank you for your response. Why is the code not working when in script tags in a stand alone html file? The script is in the <head> tags.